# In a bit of a while loop mess!

Tags: php, loops

I have spent quite some time making a function and the last 15-20 minutes trying to figure this out. I need help!

I am selecting multiple rows from the database and then running them in a while loop.

They are available on a dropdown menu.

```
<form method="POST" action="adminprocess.php">
  <fieldset>
    <p>
      <label class="left2">League:</label>
      <select name="league" class="combo">
      <?php 
        $q = $database->selectAllLeagues();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
          $theid = $row['id'];
          extract($row);
          ?>
          <option value="<? echo $theid; ?>"> 
            <? echo $format.'_'.$game.'_'.$name.'_Season '.$season;?> 
          </option>
          <?
        }
      ?>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="hidden" name="replaceleague" />
      <input type="hidden" name="format" value="<? echo $format; ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="game" value="<? echo $game; ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<? echo $name; ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="season" value="<? echo $season; ?>" />
      <input type='submit' class="button" value='Select league' />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

$theid seems to be working fine dependning on which row i select on the dropdown menu.
However, I cant get the values below in the hidden inputs to pass through the correct values from the row selected in the dropdown box.

It seems to always pass through the 4 variables from the first row of the database.

So basically, I need it to select the right row and use that data.
What am i doing wrong!!!
Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please indent your code... that would be better for everyone involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your hidden fields are initialized outside the loop, so they'll use the values that were left over from the last iteration of the `while` loop. (i.e. the last fetched row)
2. Why do you actually need the hidden fields in the first place? When you submit the form, the `league` field will contain the ID of the row selected in the drop-down box. Using the ID, you can fetch the other fields from the database when processing the form.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question about the while loop, it's because the hidden inputs are echoed outside the loop, after which data the last-iterated row from your database is used by PHP to output to those hidden inputs.

But I suggest that instead of using hidden form elements like that, you submit your form with the `<option>` with the value a user chooses, read the value (as in `$_POST['league']`), and fetch the row from your database with that ID and use it accordingly. (You may wish to keep the `replaceleague` hidden input if your application needs it of course.)

It's much easier, plus it ensures the information about the row a user chooses is coming from your database and not tampered with. In fact, for most applications this is the right way to go.